# Detect near duplicate document using simhash

Tags: python, duplicates, simhash

I've found this python project in [github](https://github.com/seomoz/simhash-py) but when I am trying to use it from my purpose to **detect near-duplicate document** e.g json, I'm not getting enough information from the **README.md** file on how to do that? It shows only to compute

```
import simhash

a = simhash.compute(...) 
b = simhash.compute(...)
simhash.num_differing_bits(a, b)
```

**AND** how to find matches using

```
import simhash
hashes = []
blocks = 4
distance = 3
matches = simhash.find_all(hashes, blocks, distance)
```

**What I've tried so far:** After cloning this repo, I've installed all the requirements but when I try to run the `setup.py` or `bench.py` it is showing

> ImportError: No module named simhash.simhash

This project is awesome but I'm having this difficulty because the **README.md** file is not very descriptive on **how to create hashes of documents?**, **how to pass hashes?** and **how detect near duplicates?**. So I need help on that how can I make hashes of my documents? Can anyone help me out on how to implement near duplicate documents detection using this **simhash** using python or provide any step by step tutorial link to implement this? By the way I've seen [that](https://moz.com/devblog/near-duplicate-detection/) but this doesn't contain full steps to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip install git+https://github.com/seomoz/simhash-py.git
```

Also for more description dlecocq has posted in the issue. below is the link for that

https://github.com/seomoz/simhash-py/issues/47